# Java: spring: why AbstractBeanFactory doesnt allow to change the parent BeanFactory?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

```
class AbstractBeanFactory

    public void setParentBeanFactory(BeanFactory parentBeanFactory) {
    if (this.parentBeanFactory != null && this.parentBeanFactory != parentBeanFactory) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already associated with parent BeanFactory: " + this.parentBeanFactory);
    }
    this.parentBeanFactory = parentBeanFactory;
}
```

My requirement is to make a chain of ApplicationContexts with one AppContext referring to other as its parent. The parentage is also extended to the corresponding `DefaultListableBeanFactory` of the AppContext also, i.e. `DefaultListableBeanFactory` of a Context refers to parent Context's `DefaultListableBeanFactory` as its parent.
This is done so that a bean residing in any Context in the chain can be searched from the bottom most AppContext.

This chain is dynamic, new AppContext gets added at the top, any AppContext can be deleted from the middle.

But when i delete an AppContext from the middle and try changing the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` parent relation, it gives the above exception.

How can i change the parent relation of the factories at runtime?

Thanks,
Regards,
Vimal

Answer (score 1):

I believe parent bean factory is designed as final and this is reasonable design choice in my opinion. Replacing it with another one would lead to many inconsistencies and unpredictable behavior.

If you have dependency on bean injected from parent context, what should happen if you replace parent context? Should this dependency be reinjected? If yes, what about prototype beans, they aren't tracked? If not, what if scope of the bean from parent context changes?

Spring does not allow partial refreshing of the context and replacing parent context sounds like an attempt at such operation.

Perhaps if you explained your problem in more details, with some examples, it would be possible to answer your question with a constructive suggestion.

Comment: i have explained the problem in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885350/java-spring-how-to-transfer-beans-from-one-classpathxmlapplicationcontext-to-a