# java: Spring: How to transfer beans from one ClassPathXMLApplicationContext to another?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

How to transfer beans from one `ClassPathXMLApplicationContext` to another?

I create one context like this

```
ClassPathXMLApplicationContext myOneContext = new ClassPathXMLApplicationContext("path to my  xml bean definitions"); // It loads 10 beans which probably refer each other

ClassPathXMLApplicationContext my2ndContext = new ClassPathXMLApplicationContext("path to my  xml bean definitions"); // It loads 2 beans, which probably refer each other
```

is it possible to transfer all beans from `my2ndContext` to `myOneContext`?

I have been getting beanFactory from `myOneContext` and getting its internal bean factory as `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry` and invoking `registerSingleton`

```
Object beanObject = my2ndContext.getBean("beanName");
DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry lbf =(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry)myOneContext.getBeanFactory();
lbf.registerSingleton("beanName", beanObject);
```

is this ok? i feel i am doing a kind of hack. also not sure what else i am missing.

Another option is to retain the beans in the same contexts and add a parent relation among the AppContexts and its bean factories.

```
myOneContext.setParent(my2ndContext);
DefaultListableBeanFactory lbf = (DefaultListableBeanFactory)myOneContext.getBeanFactory();
lbf.setParentBeanFactory(my2ndContext.getBeanFactory());
```

this way all the beans from both context are visible in the `myOneContext`

But a problem arises when i have to destroy the `my2ndContext` and i set the parent of the BeanFactory to null.

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory lbf = (DefaultListableBeanFactory)myOneContext.getBeanFactory();
lbf.setParentBeanFactory(null); <<< throws exception
```

because it doesnt allow the bean factory to be changed.

```
From Spring Sourse: AbstractBeanFactory.java
public void setParentBeanFactory(BeanFactory parentBeanFactory) {
    if (this.parentBeanFactory != null && this.parentBeanFactory != parentBeanFactory) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already associated with parent BeanFactory: " + this.parentBeanFactory);
    }
    this.parentBeanFactory = parentBeanFactory;
}
```

which way should i choose? transfer the beans OR make a parent relation. which is preferable?

Thanks,

Regards,

Vimal

Comment: Why do you need two separate contexts? Do they have to be refreshed independently? Are there any cross-dependencies? Sorry I'm throwing that many questions at you but I fail to see the big picture here and without it I can't come up with anything useful.

Comment: @mrembisz yes, they need to be refreshed independently. the first context is populated at startup, which typically contains some infrastructure beans. the second context will be created dynamically when i deploy my 'application pkg' on the running process. the package contains beans definitions which then need to be dynamically loaded. and can be later unloaded/upgraded. so in a sense, first app context is the platform and second context contains the application on it, which can be hot deployed, undeployed.

Comment: From this description I would have "platform" context which is built once upon startup. It would be parent of "dynamic" context which can be refreshed or recreated whenever required. This assumes you only need to refresh "dynamic" context. If you had to refresh "platform" context, it would result in refreshing both I suppose. I don't see the need for switching parent context here.

Comment: correct. i can make platform context as the parent of "dynamic" context. but there can be multiple applications to be deployed, so multiple "dynamic" contexts. all "dynamic" contexts have to make a chain with "platform" context at the top. and from this chain i should be able to undeploy an application. thereby destroying its corresponding "dynamic" context and rechaining the rest of the contexts(just like removing an item from single linked list). that is where the problem lies. i cannot reset parent factory of the AppContext beanFactory.

Comment: I see. I take all app contexts can't have just platform context as their parent - this requirement sounds like a blocker here and also is something I find hard to understand.

Comment: if i make all the app contexts have platform context as the parent, i guess the app contexts cannot refer to each other's beans. they can only refer to platform defined beans. which i think will be a big limitation.

Comment: Indeed they can't. But I don't perceive this as a limitation but rather as a clear separation, sparing you potential mess. Also your requirements sound like something OSGI is trying to solve. If you are bound to spring have a look here: http://www.springsource.org/osgi.

Comment: @mrembisz thanks a lot. Agreed. will be making platform context as the parent of all dynamic contexts. now if you can please submit an answer, i will select that as the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend setting up a dedicated parent context with all shared infrastructure inside. The application specific contexts would use this one as their parent. It would be possible to refresh the dynamic context while leaving shared part in parent intact.

It is best to keep parent-child hierarchy flat - one parent context and multiple child contexts. Cross-dependencies between sibling application context while tempting at first, would contribute to chaos later on and supporting such dependencies would require some non-trivial hacks or workarounds.

If this kind of sibling dependencies is a must, have a look at OSGI.